# hiding a slider image in php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am creating a property website from a database with PHP. On the description of each property listed has a slider of up to 10 images/slides. However, if there are only 6 images/slides for example; i would like to hide the remaining 6 images/slides from showing.

Here is what i have so far;

```
$sql = DB::getInstance()->query('SELECT * FROM listings WHERE id =' . Input::get('id'));

            foreach($sql->results() as $row) {

<div id="property-slider">
<section class="slider">
    <div class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">

            <li>
                <figure>
                    <a href="#"><img src="admin/<?php echo $row->img_set_1 ?>" alt="<?php echo $row->alt ?>"></a>
                </figure>
            </li>

            <li>
                <figure>
                    <a href="#"><img src="admin/<?php echo $row->img_set_2 ?>" alt="<?php echo $row->alt ?>"></a>
                </figure>
            </li>

            <li>
                <figure>
                    <a href="#"><img src="admin/<?php echo $row->img_set_3 ?>" alt="<?php echo $row->alt ?>"></a>
                </figure>
            </li>

            <li>
                <figure>
                    <a href="#"><img src="admin/<?php echo $row->img_set_5 ?>" alt="<?php echo $row->alt ?>"></a>
                </figure>
            </li>

            <li>
                <figure>
                    <a href="#"><img src="admin/<?php echo $row->img_set_6 ?>" alt="<?php echo $row->alt ?>"></a>
                </figure>
            </li>

            <li>
                <figure>
                    <a href="#"><img src="admin/<?php echo $row->img_set_7 ?>" alt="<?php echo $row->alt ?>"></a>
                </figure>
            </li>

            <li>
                <figure>
                    <a href="#"><img src="admin/<?php echo $row->img_set_8 ?>" alt="<?php echo $row->alt ?>"></a>
                </figure>
            </li>

            <li>
                <figure>
                    <a href="#"><img src="admin/<?php echo $row->img_set_9 ?>" alt="<?php echo $row->alt ?>"></a>
                </figure>
            </li>

            <li>
                <figure>
                    <a href="#"><img src="admin/<?php echo $row->img_set_10 ?>" alt="<?php echo $row->alt ?>"></a>
                </figure>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>  
</section>
</div>

}
```

I am trying to get a result simular to this, but think repeating this 10 time etc etc, just think there is a better way

```
<?php
  if(empty($row->img_set_1)) {
    echo "";
  } else {
    echo "<li>";
      echo "<figure>";
        echo "<a href='#'><img src='{admin/$row->img_set_1}'></a>";
      echo "</figure>";
    echo "</li>";
  }
?>
```

this is the function for the query

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()) {

    $this->_error = false;

    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $x = 1;
        if(count($params)) {
            foreach($params as $param) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

THIS IS AN UPDATE OF THE WORKING SLIDER---NOT IDEAL BUT IT WORKS

```
<?php
  if(empty($row->img_set_1)) {
    echo "";
  } else {
    echo "<li>";
      echo "<figure>";
        echo "<a href='#'><img src='admin/{$row->img_set_1}'></a>";
      echo "</figure>";
    echo "</li>";
  }

  if(empty($row->img_set_2)) {
    echo "";
  } else {
    echo "<li>";
      echo "<figure>";
        echo "<a href='#'><img src='admin/{$row->img_set_2}'></a>";
      echo "</figure>";
    echo "</li>";
  }

  //This repeats etc etc
```

?>

Comment: Do you have any loop in php?

Comment: Please post the portion of the code that does the query leading up to the code you have already posted.

Comment: Put you last code block in a loop -> `for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){ if(empty($row->img_set_{$i})) {...your code...} else {} }`. Then you only have the code once, but it loops through 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$x = 1;
while($x<=10) {
if(!empty($row["img_set_$x"])) {
echo "<li>";
      echo "<figure>";
        echo "<a href='#'><img src=".'{admin/'.$row["img_set_$x"].'}'."</a>";
      echo "</figure>";
    echo "</li>";
}
    $x++;
}
```

Comment: $sql = DB::getInstance()->query('SELECT * FROM listings WHERE id =' . Input::get('id'));
                
                foreach($sql->results() as $row) {

Comment: Len_D  I have added the query code that is above the slider

Comment: BTW none of your suggestions work, it just kills the slider with ni output. Sorry guys, this should be simple but i am loggers with it

Comment: Take a look at: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/v865-p7rt
This works. You may have to adjust to fit your code. For example, I hard coded the array.

Comment: Thanks :-) i will have a look. BTW i have got it to work, but i still think there is a better way than just repeating it 10 times. Thanks for you input :-)

Comment: Len_D i have looked at phpfiddle.org/main/code/v865-p7rt although the theory of that is correct, to which i have tried already, unfortunately it does't work, it just kills the slider and displays no image

Comment: If it doesn't work, it's a coding thing on your end. Can you post my code integrated into yours so i can see what you did?